# what's the meaning of the parameter 'filters' in keras.conv2d method?

Tags: python, keras

all
I'm newer in Keras. I'm reading the documents about method conv2d. My question is what's the meaning of the parameter 'filters' in keras.conv2d method? Is it implicate the number of kernel? And does this parameter impact the shape of the output? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Yes it is the number of kernels applied to the image, and it impacts the shape of the output.

Comment: https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/

This should be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

`filters` for a 2D convolution is the number of output channels after the convolution. Specifically, as stated in the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/),

> Integer, the dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the number of output filters in the convolution).

For example

```py
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same")(input)
```

On, say, an input where `input.shape` is `(224, 224, 3)`, would produce a result of shape `(224, 224, 64)`.

**EDIT**

In the documentation for Conv2D, this is formulated a bit more clearly:

> Input shape
>
> 4D tensor with shape: (batch, channels, rows, cols) if data_format is
>   "channels_first" or 4D tensor with shape: (batch, rows, cols,
>   channels) if data_format is "channels_last".
>
> Output shape
>
> 4D tensor with shape: (batch, filters, new_rows, new_cols) if
>   data_format is "channels_first" or 4D tensor with shape: (batch,
>   new_rows, new_cols, filters) if data_format is "channels_last". rows
>   and cols values might have changed due to padding.